# Set Combobox dropdown to max columns of datatable

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, datatable

I'm parsing in data from a CSV file and have it all in a datatable, now what I'd like to do is create a combobox that has a dropdown menu with numbers equal to the max number of colummns (or entries in each row, which translates to elements in each array I believe) in that datatable.

For example, if in my datatable I have 4 rows, each with 10 columns, I'd like to have a combobox with a dropdown menu of items 1-10.

In pseudo-code:

```
get datatable max column number
iterate up until max column number, adding items to dropdown list
```

I'm sure this is relatively simple, I just don't know C# very well.

Currently I'm hard-coding in the values like so:

```
List<int> colNums1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(colNums1.ConvertAll<string>(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

And I'd like to make it adaptable, because this obviously isn't going to work for real csvs, as they won't all have 10 columns. Thanks!

Comment: People will be glad to help you, but you need to at least show something you've attempted.

Comment: Define element.  How do you create a DataTable that is not uniform?

Comment: Edited to reflect the comments, I assumed that datatables could be nonuniform and wanted to handle that case as well, but I think for my purposes I can assume they'll be uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 1; i < myDataTable.Columns.Count+1; i++)
   {
      comboBox1.Items.Add(i); 
   }
```